# Query String to Path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I currently have this as my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(assets|modules|plugins)/ - [NC,L,QSA]                                                                                                                                                                
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s                                                                                                                                                                  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]                                                                                                                                                             
RewriteRule (.*) - [NC,L,QSA,S=3]                                                                                                                                                                                   
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1?type=$2 [NC,QSA]                                                                                                                                                                       
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This was moved from an apache vhost config to .htaccess but I am getting 404's.

For example: I would like this page http://stripsync.com/index.php?page=venue to look like this http://stripsync.com/venue

What am I doing wrong? All help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this, removing opening forward slashes since you moved it to `.htaccess` (which doesn't include them in the match), and removing `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` since `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` already has it in this context.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(assets|modules|plugins)/ - [NC,L]                                                                                                                                                                
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_REWRITTEN} =1 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1?type=$2 [QSA,L,E=REWRITTEN:1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,E=REWRITTEN:1]
</IfModule>
```

I removed unused flags and capturing.

Comment: When I use your example I get a 500 error.

Would it help to provide example of my global variables, and index.php file?

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the rules, can you try again? If it's still a 500, please let me know what the error log says.